# forwarding_to_node_failed in Selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, spock, geb

I am running Selenium Webdriver with PhantomJS. My test cases are written using Geb and Spock using Maven and are meant to run headlessly using PhantomJSDriver running on the Selenium nodes. I have one Selenium hub and three node servers. I have observed almost 50% of the times a few of the tests are failing running through one of the nodes with the error forwarding_to_node_failed. As per the following link I downgraded my Selenium version to 2.41.0, but it didn't help:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7396

As part "Tips for running with grid" section of the following link it has been mentioned to make sure that each thread deallocates its webdriver resource independently of any other tests running on other threads:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

I was trying to implement the same in PhantomJS with the following code:

..................................................

```
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.*


    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "C:/Users/Test/Downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs.exe")

def setup() {
    driver = { new PhantomJSDriver() }
}

def cleanup(){
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
}

baseUrl = ....
```

..........................................................

But it is failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

### ..........................................................

### Test set: CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.619 sec <<< FAILURE!
test CPSearch Home Page is up(CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec)  Time elapsed: 1.06 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.(CookieManager.java:59)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.(WebClient.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.newWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:289)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.createWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:184)
    at geb.driver.NameBasedDriverFactory.getDriver(NameBasedDriverFactory.groovy:44)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:361)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:350)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:405)
    at geb.Page.to(Page.groovy:195)
    at geb.Browser.via(Browser.groovy:488)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:448)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:426)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:54)
    at CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec.test CPSearch Home Page is up(CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec.groovy:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.set.ListOrderedSet
    ... 22 more
test CPSearch Home Page is up(CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec)  Time elapsed: 1.115 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.(CookieManager.java:59)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.(WebClient.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.newWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:289)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.createWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:184)
    at geb.driver.NameBasedDriverFactory.getDriver(NameBasedDriverFactory.groovy:44)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:361)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:350)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
    at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
    at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:788)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:44)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:39)
test CPSearch Home Page is up(CPSearchHomePage_001TestSpec)  Time elapsed: 1.125 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.(CookieManager.java:59)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.(WebClient.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.newWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:289)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.createWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.(HtmlUnitDriver.java:184)
    at geb.driver.NameBasedDriverFactory.getDriver(NameBasedDriverFactory.groovy:44)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:361)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:350)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.Browser.clearCookies(Browser.groovy:496)
    at geb.Browser.clearCookiesQuietly(Browser.groovy:504)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.resetBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:48)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.cleanup(GebSpec.groovy:71)
..........................................................
Any help on this matter is appreciated. Thanks

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.gebish.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>geb-maven-example</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>Geb Maven Example</name>
  <url>http://gebish.org</url>
  <properties>
    <gebVersion>0.9.3</gebVersion>
    <seleniumVersion>2.41.0</seleniumVersion>
    <groovyVersion>2.3.6</groovyVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
      <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
      <version>${gebVersion}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>*Spec.*</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7-groovy-1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                 <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>latest</version>
        </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.gmaven
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        gmaven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.4,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshot</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
</project>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace with the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Complete stack trace with the NoClassDefFoundError added.

Comment: Is the commons-collections.jar file in your classpath or Maven build?

Comment: Added common-collections and common-logging but getting the same error. PFB a copy of my pom.xml:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: I have added commons-collections and commons-logging to my pom.xml, but still getting the same error. Have updated copy of my pom @Jason

Comment: common-collections is as part of my Maven build currently, added in the pom.xml.